# How can I trigger Parent form event from Child form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, winforms, events

I have a parent form from which I create and instance of another form.(child form)

I am trying to trigger an event on the parent form from the child form. 
(I have tried reading a few similar questions on SO but they were either in c# or had too little explanation for a rookie like me.

**Parent Form:**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

            Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)

            Dim frmjvauth As New frmjventry_Auth
            frmjvauth.Show()
            frmjvauth.txtjvnumver.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("jvnumber").Value
            frmjvauth.showjv()
    End Sub

Private Sub child_Change(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox("hey")
    End Sub
```

**Child Form:**

```
Private Sub frmjventry_Auth_FormClosed(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    RaiseEvent child_Change(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: Having `child_Change`, I suppose you have a `child` object and an `Change` event. What's the type of child and what is `Change` event?

Comment: @RezaAghaei its just a name that i chose . It could be anything. I am trying to raise a event on parent form on `FormClosed` event of child

Comment: It's dependent to implementation, for example if you want to raise `Click` event of button1, you can call `PerformClick` of that button. a better solution would be putting the logic that you want to run in that event, in a public method and call that method from your child form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggering an event from outside of your class is dependent to implementation of your event and your class.
An event raise when a specific case happens, for example when changing a property value, when click on a button and so on. To trigger that event, you should simulate that happening, for example, you should set a value for the property that you want to fire its change event or for example for a button, you should call `PerformClick` method of that button.

But in general, it's better to create a public method in your parent form and put your logic there and call that method from outside of the form.

For example I suppose you need to trigger `Click` event of button 1 and have this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    //Some logic here
End Sub
```

**Option 1**

You can add a public method and move your logic there and also call that method in `button1_Click`:

```
Public Sub MyLogic()
    //Some logic here
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyLogic()
End Sub
```

then from outside, you can simply use the logic this way:

```
//I suppose f is an instance of your form
f.MyLogic()
```

**Option 2**

You can make your `Button1` public, go to designer and select your `Button1` and set value of `Modifier` property to `public`. Then you can use this code from outside of your form:

```
//I suppose f is an instance of your form
f.Button1.PerformClick()
```

**Option 3**

For your hand made events you can create a public method in your form that raise your event:

```
Public Event YourEvent()

Public Sub OnYourEvent()
    RaiseEvent YourEvent()
End Sub
```

And then use it outside of form this way:

```
//I suppose f is an instance of your form
f.OnYourEvent()
```

**Sample**

Here is a sample containing 2 forms:

```
'Here is the code for parent form
Public Class ParentFormClass
    Public Sub MyLogic()
        MessageBox.Show("My Logic is Running!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MyLogic()
    End Sub    

    'This is the way that you pass an instance of parent to child
    Private Sub ShowChildFormButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowChildFormButton.Click
        Dim f As New ChildFormClass(Me)
    End Sub
End Class

'Here is the code for child form
Public Class ChildFormClass
    Private MyParentForm As ParentFormClass

    Public Sub New(form As ParentFormClass)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        MyParentForm = form
    End Sub

    Private Sub CallParentFormMethodButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CallParentFormMethodButton.Click
        MyParentForm.MyLogic()
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: How to do you get instance of parent form on child form? 
I write `Dim obj as new ParentForm` that would mean creating a new instance .

Comment: You should pass an instance of your parent form to `YourChildForm` in constructor or as a property. For example you can add a constructor `Public Sub New(parentForm AS YourPerentForm)` for your child form and then store `parentForm` in a field of your class and then use it.  For example when you want to create your child form you can use `Dim child As New YourChildForm(Me)`

Comment: Since passing the instance of your parent form is not subject of this question, I prefer to not post the code here, but I shared a snippet here for you https://dotnetfiddle.net/uzwPzt

Comment: I really think you should add this link in your post. Although I did not ask for how to pass instance of parent form to child, a little extra information doesn't hurt. It will be helpful to many who are a rookie like me. Thanks.

Comment: I'll Add it if you think it may be helpful for other users too :)

Comment: Updated, hope you find it helpful:)

Comment: @Arbaaz Thank you for your feedback :) By the way, while you can mark only one answer as accepted, you can vote up as many answer you find helpful including accepted one by click on up arrow. You can also vote up for good questions too :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a public event to your child form, and call your routine in its handler on the main form. Also passing Nothing when raising the event is a bad idea. You should pass Me as the sender object, and a new EventArgs object as e.

```
Public Class ChildForm
    Public Event OnChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Private Sub frmjventry_Auth_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles frmjventry_Auth.FormClosed
        RaiseEvent OnChanged(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MainForm
    Private Sub ChildForm_OnChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChildForm.OnChanged
        DoSomething()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomething()
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am getting a wavely line under ` Handles frmjventry_Auth.FormClosed` on child form . 

 `Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types`

Comment: Just declare your form WithEvents, or alternatively add the handler manually through AddHandler.